# Good plugins for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

I want to know more plugins or gems which can help to make my rails application more powerful and efficient and easy to handle.

```
Like 
    mysqlplus instead of mysql
    memcached
    delayed_job
    resque
    capistrano
```

Comment: I don't think adding plugins to your project without reason is likely to improve your app. Better to identify problem areas or areas for improvement in your app and then seek solutions. Don't try to solve problems that you don't have (yet).

Comment: i just want to get ideas about different plugins which are good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the "Must Have" Ruby Gems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822980/what-are-the-must-have-ruby-gems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the following plugins/gems to your list:

1. Authlogic (or Devise)
2. declarative_authorization (or CanCan)
3. Cucumber and Capybara
4. RSpec or Shoulda
5. Factory Girl
6. Haml and Sass (with Compass)
7. Paperclip
8. will_paginate
9. Formtastic
10. Searchlogic
11. RVM (last but by no means least)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'powerful'? :) Efficient - that depends on what exactly your application is doing.

Anyway, for a good eye-pick on what are your options, you may visit [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/).

Comment: I have listed plugins which are helpful to handle applications. So i just want to know about more plugins which will help. Thanks